# matplotlibのcolormapの色を絶対的な値で決めたい

Tags: python, python3, matplotlib

python3にて、matplotlib (Ver.3.3.3)を使用してスペクトログラムを書こうとしています。
例えばカラーマップを指定し、信号`sig_1`のスペクトログラムを作成し保存したい場合、以下のように書いて動作することを確認しました。

#### コード1

```
fig = plt.figure()
pxx, freq, bins, t = plt.specgram(sig_1 ,Fs = 48000, cmap = 'jet')
plt.colorbar()
fig.savefig('spectrogram_1.png')
```

一方、今行いたいのは、信号`sig_1`と信号`sig_2`のスペクトログラムを目で見て比較することです。そこでコード1を使って

#### コード2

```
fig_1 = plt.figure()
pxx, freq, bins, t = plt.specgram(sig_1 ,Fs = 48000, cmap = 'jet')
plt.colorbar()
fig_1.savefig('spectrogram_1.png')

fig_2 = plt.figure()
pxx, freq, bins, t = plt.specgram(sig_2 ,Fs = 48000, cmap = 'jet')
plt.colorbar()
fig_2.savefig('spectrogram_2.png')
```

としようと思ったのですが、カラーマップの色の縮尺が自動で調整されてしまうようで、`spectrogram_1.png`と`spectrogram_2.png`とで色合いを見て単純に比較することができません。例えばsig_2にsig_1 * 10を代入してみても、描画されるスペクトログラムの色合いは同じで、colorbarを表示させると、各色に対応する数値のほうがずれてしまいまっています[※]。これを、colorbarの各色に対応する数値は同じにして、描画の色合いが変わるようにしたい[※※]です。

どのようにすれば良いか、方法をご存じの方教えてもらえないでしょうか？
（[※]もしくは[※※]を上手く言語化できず、上手く検索ができず、このような長文になってしまいました。読みにくくてすみません。）

Comment: この辺の記事が参考になるかも？ [matplotlibでカラーバーの範囲を思い通りにする](https://qiita.com/kumamupooh/items/c793a6781a753eca6d8e), [matplotlibでカラーバーの範囲を設定する方法](https://teratail.com/questions/268456), [Python/Matplotlib - Colorbar Range and Display Values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5826592/9014308), [Set Colorbar Range in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3373256/9014308)

Comment: 頂いた最後の[Set Colorbar Range in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3373256/9014308)が上手く動きました！`pxx, freq, bins, t = plt.specgram(sig_1 ,Fs = 48000, cmap = 'jet', vmin = -40.0, vmax = 40.0)`のようにすることで指定することができました。ありがとうございます！

Comment: こちらをベストアンサーとしたかったのですがコメントのためできず、解決済にするため自己回答しました。もしよければ再度回答として投稿頂ければと思います。このままでも良ければ、自己回答をベストアンサー扱い(2日経たないとできないため、2日後くらいに）したいと思いますので、そのまま放置ください。

Comment: 細かい実態は分からず紹介しただけなので、自己解決ということで良いと思われます。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

頂いたコメント（コメント1、[kunif](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/26370/kunif)さんより）で解決したため、解決済み扱いにするために自分でコメントを書いておきます。

> 頂いたコメントの最後の[Set Colorbar Range in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3373256/9014308)が上手く動きました！
> `pxx, freq, bins, t = plt.specgram(sig_1 ,Fs = 48000, cmap = 'jet', vmin = -40.0, vmax = 40.0)`のようにすることで指定することができました。